# Get total rows in joined and grouped query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I have a reasonably complicated query in my rails application, 
I join table A and table B so I can thoroughly search both tables
I then group table A on its ID to remove duplicates created by my inner join on table B
I then require the count of the remaining records so that I can paginate the results.

However doing that is giving me the following exception when I try to get the count:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "game_id" is ambiguous
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, game_id AS game_id, region AS ...
                                      ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, game_id AS game_id, region AS region FROM "game_data" INNER JOIN "player_participants" ON "player_participants"."game_id" = "game_data"."game_id" WHERE "player_participants"."region" = $1 AND "game_data"."region" = 'NA1' AND "game_data"."status" = 1 GROUP BY "game_data"."game_id", "game_data"."region"):
```

Here is my rails code:

```
games = GameDatum.joins(:player_participants).where(
  player_participants: pp_data,
  game_data: g_data
).group(:game_id).order(created_at: :desc).page(page).per(records)

games_json = {}
games_json[:pages] = games.total_pages
```

games.total_pages uses .count which is what is giving me issues.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ERROR:  column reference "game_id" is ambiguous
```

Looks like you have `game_id` column in both of your tables. So, use `table_name.column_name` convention in your query. Use `.group('player_participants.game_id')` instead of `group(:game_id)` if you want to use the `game_id` from `player_participants` table:

```
  games = GameDatum
    .joins(:player_participants)
    .where(player_participants: pp_data, game_data: g_data)
    .group('player_participants.game_id')
    .order(created_at: :desc)
    .page(page)
    .per(records)
```

Comment: Thanks fixed it perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

From a pure SQL answer, the issue is that the game_id appears in both tables, so you need to be specific in the query to which one to use such as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, "player_participants".game_id AS game_id, region AS region FROM "game_data" INNER JOIN "player_participants" ON "player_participants"."game_id" = "game_data"."game_id" WHERE "player_participants"."region" = $1 AND "game_data"."region" = 'NA1' AND "game_data"."status" = 1 GROUP BY "game_data"."game_id", "game_data"."region"
```

Therefore I would suggest you try adding the table.column_name to your group by such as:

.group('player_participants.game_id')

Sorry that I can not be more help.